# Send email in the background in SVN post-commit

Tags: bash, email, svn, post-commit-hook

I'm trying to send an email to a member of our testing team when a specific file is committed to our SVN repository. I've got the `post-commit` hook working properly using `sendmail` with all the proper contents, but the problem is that running the `sendmail` command takes ages and members of the team will complain. I've logged a message to the TortoiseSVN console letting the users know what's going on but it doesn't appear until *after* the mail is sent, rendering the message essentially useless.

I have two questions:

1. Can I somehow make my hook output this message before `sendmail` runs? The `echo` command is before `sendmail` but it doesn't seem to do much
2. Can I force the `sendmail` command to run in the background?

Here is the script:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
TXN_NAME="$3"

# Make sure that the log message contains some text.
SVNLOOK=/opt/bitnami/subversion/bin/svnlook
SENDMAIL=/usr/sbin/sendmail

AUTHOR=$($SVNLOOK author -r "$REV" "$REPOS")
FOUND=$($SVNLOOK changed -r "$REV" "$REPOS" | grep -Pc '[U]\s+.+(file.txt)$')

MAILLOCATION=/home/bitnami/svn/test

MAILMESSAGE="To: tester@mycorp.com\nFrom: subversion@mycorpdev\nSubject: File was modified\n\n$AUTHOR modified the file"

if [ $FOUND -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "You've modified the file, yada yada yada" >&2
  echo "Note: Your commit did not fail, even though the text says it did." >&2


  $SENDMAIL -t < $MAILLOCATION &



  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

I've tried using `eval $($SENDMAIL -t < $MAILLOCATION) &` and a few other things as the `sendmail` command but nothing has helped.

Comment: Btw.: I suggest to check why sendmail command takes ages.

Comment: What about https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/ or http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/mailer/ ?

Comment: @bahrep That's for VisualSVN. I'm not using it.

Comment: @Cyrus I suspect it's because the server is underpowered. Something I can't change.

Comment: The second link should work for any svn server and repo

Comment: My bad I thought it was all one

Comment: Oh yeah I tried `mailer.py` but it just runs, doesn't send mail and doesn't output any error or messages.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
nohup $SENDMAIL -t < $MAILLOCATION &>/dev/null &
disown
```

Taken from [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/)